# How unique is the sequential portion of the VIN?

Tags: vin

Digits 12 through 17 are the sequential portion of a VIN. These are unique to a vehicle, but can we be more specific? For example, can a Nissan Sentra made in two different plants have the same sequence number? What about from two different model years? Since these attributes (plant, year) are encoded elsewhere in the VIN, it stands to reason there could be two Sentra's with the same sequence number and their VIN's still unique. Also, is there a standard around this or could it differ by manufacturer?

Comment: Have you decoded a vin?

Comment: 6 digits only gives 999,999 different numbers. For an international car model (e.g. Opel) that is not enough unique numbers without some extra fields like model year and assembly plant.

Comment: @alephzero Opel is a manufacturer with different models. A long-running model typically has generations spanning five years or so. I would think something about the vehicle descriptor (not keyed to plant or model year) would change during a long production run of some generation of some model -- i.e. way before hitting the million mark. Maybe the better question is, what variables trigger the start of a new sequence or series (or the allowing of duplicates).

Comment: With most manufacturers that is the Serial number of the production of the car and may or may not be unique.